# tcp send with its real length instead of using sizeof data

Tags: networking, sizeof, tcp

I am trying to send a small packet via tcp but i have a problem with the size of it.
My data is 255 byte buffer:

```
buffer[0] = 0x00;
buffer[1] = 0x04;
buffer[2] = 0x06;
buffer[3] = 0x08;
buffer[4] = 0x01;
buffer[5] = 0x01;
```

and i use

```
send(sockfd,buffer,6,MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_DONTWAIT);
```

but data can not be send when i use 6. If i use send like:

```
 send(sockfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer),MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_DONTWAIT);
```

then data is sent but recevier has to parse extra 250 0x00 byte and i don't want it. Why 6 is no ok. I also try 10 randomly nothing changes.

Here is my receiver code Anything writes at that side:

```
        while(1) {
           ret = recv(socket,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
           if (ret > 0) 
                 printf("recv success");
            else
            {
               if (ret == 0)
                   printf("recv failed (orderly shutdown)");
               else
                   printf("recv failed (errno:%d)",errno);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "data can not be send when i use 6"? Please check the return value of `send`.

Comment: What is the other side reporting when you `recv()` those 6 bytes?  (You can most definitely give any amount of data to `send()`, though it may not accept it all -- check the return code.)

Comment: It returns 6 but i can not see on wireshark and the receiver could not recv it, weird.

Comment: 'Could not receive it' is not an adequate problem description. If the peer's `recv()` returned 6, there are 6 bytes of data in the buffer. If that didn't work, nothing would work, including StackOverflow. You will need to post the code that you allege 'could not receive it'.

Comment: I also edit my receiver code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of MSG_DONTWAIT. This is only useful when you have something else to do when the socket send buffer is full and the data can't be sent. As you aren't checking the result of send(), clearly you aren't interested in that condition. However you *must* check the result of send anyway, as you may have got an error, so fix your code to do that as well.

Comment: It is a cgi code which is called from a web server and if the process is not end i can not see anything (printf etc) But sorry for the wrong information before i saw my package on wireshark and its acknowledge but receiver can not receive it. Anything returns from recv(). Somehow the package does not reach to it, i guess

Comment: I found the problem it is a little endian/big endian problem. I have to    put two bytes of length reverse. The problem has solved. Thank you.